# Scanner from FileIO does not give desired result

Tags: java, file-io, split

I have text in a txt file which reads
 (yoga class;12;2;11-12;the description;11;2019;11;2)
when i try to print specific fields like field[4] or field[0]
i get classdescription and the2 respectively.
How do i get "the description" as it is when i print a field?

```
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String [] fields = sc.next().split(";");
            for (int i =4; i<fields.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(fields[0]);
            }
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Scanner uses " " as a delimiter. You expect `sc.next()` to return a complete line. So you need to set EOL as delimiter:

```
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

It can help to put the output sc.next() in a String variable and print it to verify if it returns what you expect:

```
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String line=sc.next();
    String [] fields = line.split(";");
    System.out.println(fields[4]);
}
```